# finishActivity() not working as intended in Android

Tags: java, android

Following Scenario:

I got 4 Activities, A, B1, B2, and C

Activity A calls B1 by:

```
    public void toB1(View view)
    {
       Intent b1 = new Intent(this, B1Activity.class);
       startActivityForResult(b1, 2);
    }
```

Activity B1 calls B2 by:

```
    public void toB2(View view)
    {
        Intent b2 = new Intent(this, B2Activity.class);
        startActivity(b2);
    }
```

Then, when B2 has finished its work it should call C and close B1 and B2 by:

```
    public void toC(View view)
    {
        Intent c = new Intent(this, CActivity.class);
        finish();
        finishActivity(2);
        startActivity(c);
    }
```

But now, when being at C and clicking the return key, I get directed to B1 instead of A.

But B1 should be finished, is there an error in my code or do I misunderstand the concept of `startActivityForResult` ?

Comment: check my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I solve it look below for that you have to create `Singleton`,

**B1Activity.java**

```
 public static B1Activity instance = null; //declare it global
```

And start intent this way.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent b2 = new Intent(B1Activity.this, B2Activity.class);
                startActivity(b2);
            }
```

and create this method

```
 @Override
    public void finish() {
        super.finish();
        instance = null;
    }
```

Now in **B2Activity.java** use this code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent c = new Intent(B2Activity.this, CActivity.class);
                if(B1Activity.instance != null){
                    B1Activity.instance.finish();
                }
                B2Activity.this.finish();
                c.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                startActivity(c);
            }
```

Comment: @DividedByZero see my answer and then tell me.